# Package Manager Console not working Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

This is what I get when I open it, anyone had this issue before? Never happened to me:

```
Could not find file 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\typesv3.ps1xml'.
Could not find file 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Event.Format.ps1xml'.
Could not find file 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Event.Format.ps1xml'.
```

update: after adding those entries to devenv.config now I get:

```
There were errors in loading the format data file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\AUEN3JAD.VIJ\Modules\NuGet\NuGet.Format.ps1xml, Error in file C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\AUEN3JAD.VIJ\Modules\NuGet\NuGet.Format.ps1xml: '', hexadecimal value 0x13, is an invalid character. Line 311, position 36.
There were errors in loading the format data file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\AUEN3JAD.VIJ\Modules\NuGet\NuGet.Format.ps1xml, Error in file C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\AUEN3JAD.VIJ\Modules\NuGet\NuGet.Format.ps1xml: '', hexadecimal value 0x13, is an invalid character. Line 311, position 36.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding these lines to devenv.exe.config file in the runtime section. It may work.

```
 <runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Management.Automation" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.PowerShell.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: after doing this, reinstalled the nuget package manager extension and it's good to go !

Comment: Frankly, this looks like magic. I recommend that you only resort to this after spending literally days uninstalling, reinstalling, system restoring, etc.... or just save a lot of time and try it. 

The culprit for me was the installation of the extension: "Powershell Tools for Visual Studio." It broke VS2013 AND VS2012!

Comment: For reference, I am on Windows 7.

Comment: For quick reference, the default location of this file is Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE

Answer (score 2):

To do this, click Start, type Command Prompt or cmd in the Search box, right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as administrator. If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a confirmation, type the password, or click Allow.[image]

Type Command 
**C:\windows\system32>sfc /scannow**

Answer (score 0):

Adding the lines indicated above worked for VS2013, but then I had the same issue for VS2015, and it didn't work there. What worked there was Ed Vowles' comment here: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2836:

"I was able to resolve this problem by installing (or reinstalling) PowerShell from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395 (choosing this version: Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3134760-x64.msu for my windows 7 machine) and restarting."