# nuget package manager console - Could not find file

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have an issue in Visual Studio 2013 in that the package manager console will no longer initialize and shows the error

> "Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\IDE\WSMan.format.ps1xml'."

I have tried renaming the Extensions folder and manually installing NuGet. I have run a repair of VS 2013 all to no avail.

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please uninstall the NuGet Packages Manager for Visual Studio from Tools menu -> Extensions and Updates -> Installed -> NuGet Packages Manager for Visual Studio in Visual Studio menu and reinstall it in that menu again.

And others who also have this issue in another thread provide other workaround, please refer to:

[Package Manager Console not working Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728786/package-manager-console-not-working-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: I cannot uninstall NuGet via the GUI as I get the process cannot access the file because it's being used by another process error. I have already tried the stuff in the post you linked also.

Comment: Do you mean when you uninstall the NuGet through the menu in Visual Studio, you get a prompt about it is being used by another process? Please close all programs except Visual Studio to make sure doesn't have other programs uses this process. And please run your Visual Studio as administrator to make sure it has enough permissions to do any operations.

Comment: Yes when I try and uninstall NuGet through the menu in VS. VS is the process which has the file locked, nothing else. VS is also run with admin rights

Comment: Please uninstall and reinstall with command line, detailed steps please refer to: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Mar/01/Registering-and-Unregistering-a-VSIX-Extension-from-the-Command-Line

Comment: File is still locked when uninstalling via cmd line: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1138#issuecomment-224973010